# Cannot get variable to send using $.ajax({data}) to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, slim

I have tried these **JS** code combos:

```
var aion_settings = [];

function aion_save_settings(){

    //Users on the Site Frontend
    $('.setting-site-users').each(function(){
        aion_settings[$(this).prop('id')]=$(this).is(':checked');
    });

    console.log(aion_settings);

    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'/save_settings',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            settings: function(){
                return aion_settings;
            },
            other_data: 'Other Data'
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

and...

```
function aion_save_settings(){

    var aion_settings = [];

    //Users on the Site Frontend
    $('.setting-site-users').each(function(){
        aion_settings[$(this).prop('id')]=$(this).is(':checked');
    });

    console.log(aion_settings);

    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'/save_settings',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            settings: aion_settings,
            other_data: 'Other Data'
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

..and

```
var aion_settings = [];

function aion_save_settings(){

    //Users on the Site Frontend
    $('.setting-site-users').each(function(){
        aion_settings[$(this).prop('id')]=$(this).is(':checked');
    });

    console.log(aion_settings);

    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'/save_settings',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            settings: aion_settings,
            other_data: 'Other Data'
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

..and these combos with:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url:'/save_settings',
    dataType:'json',
    data:aion_settings,
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

---

On this [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) page it even has this example:

```
var xmlDocument = [create xml document];
var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});

xmlRequest.done(handleResponse);
```

---

On the receiving side, I have this **PHP** code:

```
$app->post('/save_settings',function() use ($app){

    $aion_settings=$app->request()->post();

    var_dump($aion_settings);

    //Save the aion_settings
    if(aion_logged_in_user_super()){

        global $aion_db;
        if(is_array($aion_settings)) foreach($aion_settings as $setting_key => $setting){

            //Get the setting's ID
            $current_setting = array();
            $current_setting = $aion_db->queryFirstRow("SELECT id FROM settings WHERE setting_key=%s",$setting_key);

            if(!isset($current_setting['id'])) $current_setting['id']=NULL;

            $aion_db->insertUpdate('settings',array(
                'id'=>$current_setting['id'],
                'setting_key'=>$setting_key,
                'value'=>serialize($setting)
            ));
        }
    }
});
```

The `aion_settings` is setup correctly just before the `$.ajax` request is sent. But, the object `settings` is not caught on the PHP side, though `other_data` is caught? The last line below shows the object ready via `console.log` but not set via `$.ajax`. I'm stumped, any help?

[image: Chrome DEV tools showing PHP and JS side before var is sent]

[image: Screenshot of the code]

Comment: What happens when you do `var_dump($_POST['settings']);`? Do you get an undefined error?

Comment: Same thing. That's why I think it's on the JS end before it's sent over.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter of your [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function should have the following format:

```
data: {
    'settings': aion_settings,
    'other_data': 'Other Data'
},
```

Comment: I will give it a shot, but I'm not sure why `other_data` would send.

Comment: Same result, didn't help.

Comment: @aubreypwd That's strange. Try moving the declaration of your `aion_settings` variable (the `var aion_settings = [];`) to the global context, outside of the function `aion_save_settings`. Maybe the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function is not able to reach it for some reason.

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` display exactly?

Comment: Nothing in my example above, as it's expecting a `json` object, and a `var_dump` is expressed on the PHP site.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

**JS Side:**

```
function aion_save_settings(){

    var aion_settings = new Object();   

    //Users on the Site Frontend
    $('.setting-site-users').each(function(){
        aion_settings[$(this).prop('id')]=$(this).is(':checked');
    });

    console.log(aion_settings);

    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'/save_settings',
        dataType:'json',
        data:aion_settings,
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

---

**PHP Side:**

```
$app->post('/save_settings',function() use ($app){

    $aion_settings=$app->request()->post(); 

    var_dump($aion_settings);

    //Save the aion_settings
    if(aion_logged_in_user_super()){

        global $aion_db;
        if(is_array($aion_settings)) foreach($aion_settings as $setting_key => $setting){

            //Get the setting's ID
            $current_setting = array();
            $current_setting = $aion_db->queryFirstRow("SELECT id FROM settings WHERE setting_key=%s",$setting_key);

            if(!isset($current_setting['id'])) $current_setting['id']=NULL;

            $aion_db->insertUpdate('settings',array(
                'id'=>$current_setting['id'],
                'setting_key'=>$setting_key,
                'value'=>serialize($setting)
            ));
        }
    }
});
```

---

Please compare with my question above.

[image]

[image]